# Tell WIA and TWAIN sources apart in code

Tags: java, c#, twain, wia, image-scanner

Using TWAIN, in the code it has separate identities for sources 'HP scanner WIA' and 'HP scanner TWAIN'. These are the same scanner using different interfaces.

Is there anyway to tell that multiple sources are from the same scanner? (Yes I can see the name but I want to filter out WIA IF it has both)

Comment: If you're able to see the name, why don't you just filter out anything that has "WIA" in the description from the list of scanner interfaces?

Comment: Because in some cases the scanner may only support the WIA interface for scanning.

Comment: So for every instance of each scanner, only remove the WIA interface when it isn't the only one present.  Seems easy enough to me.

Comment: Ok but the only way to tell they are the same scanner is the text. So for instance:                                                                                                  Dell V310-V510 Series TWAIN,
HP Officejet 6500 E710n-z TWAIN,
WIA-HP Officejet 6500 E710n-z

Comment: So use the text if it's available?  Compare the names to verify that they're identical minus that piece, and then remove the one you don't want?